# transform item value in array/slice

Tags: go

I want to create a new array where each value is 2 times the corresponding value in the original array, what's wrong with my code?

```
func main() {
  myArray := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
  var newArray = []string

  for i, arr := range myArray {
    newArray = newArray[i] * 2
  }

  fmt.Println(newArray)
}
```

Comment: `"abd" * 2  = ?`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use an integer slice instead of a string slice. i.e. `[]string{"1", "2", "3"}` -> `[]int{1, 2, 3}`.
2. Types are not values. i.e. `var newArray = []string` is an invalid statement. To initialize an empty slice omit the `=` operator, or use a composite type literal, or even better in this case, use `make` with the length of `myArray`.
3. Unused block variables are illegal in Go. i.e. The `arr` in `for i, arr := myArray {` is not used within the loop and will therefore cause a compile time error.
4. You cannot multiply a string with an integer. i.e. `newArray[i] * 2` where `newArray` is of type `[]string` is illegal and will cause compile time error.
5. You cannot change the type of a variable. i.e. `newArray = newArray[i] * 2` if `newArray` is of type `[]int` the statement is illegal because `newArray[i] * 2` would evaluate to `int` and you cannot assign `int` to a variable of type `[]int`.

```golang
func main() {
    myArray := []int{1, 2, 3}
    newArray := make([]int, len(myArray))

    for i := range myArray {
        newArray[i] = myArray[i] * 2
    }

    fmt.Println(newArray)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Tc0-51GiAhS

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few things wrong with your syntax.
You are declaring your arrays wrong ( your first one declares a myArray as a slice, your second one is invalid and won't compile ), and you are trying to multiply strings.
You are declaring arr but not using it which will also give a compile error.

This snippet will do what you want with ints:

```
myArray := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
newArray := myArray // copies the original array to a new one

for i := range myArray { // don't care about the value, only the index
    newArray[i] *= 2  // double the values in the new array
}

fmt.Println(newArray)
```

Another alternative without first copying the original array:

```
myArray := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
newArray := [3]int{}

for i := range myArray {
    newArray[i] = myArray[i] * 2
}

fmt.Println(newArray)
```

Comment: it's simpler than I thought, thanks!